# django returning or posting wrong template html?

Tags: python, django, url

I developed a django project named "dms" and an app which name is "add_excel" last month. The app receieves excel files from web page and store the data into mysql database. Today I added another two apps, "add_struc" and "homepage", which should be another function app and the homepage app. But something odd shows up. After I clicked the "upload" button in "add_excel" app, instead of it's original functions, it redirects to "homepage" without doing anything to the database.

The VS Code shows:

> [18/Apr/2019 11:08:00] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 317 # I opened the
>   homepage
>       [18/Apr/2019 11:08:02] "GET /addexcel/index/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1341 # I clicked to the "add_excel" app hyperlink
>       [18/Apr/2019 11:08:20] "POST /homepage/index/ HTTP/1.1" 200 317 #

I clicked "upload" but it redirected me to homepage again.

If I delete the homepage url in the urls.py for the whole project, and click the upload button again, it says:

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  POST Request
>   URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/homepage/index/ Using the URLconf defined
>   in dms.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> ^admin/ ^$ [name='index'] ^addexcel/ ^addstruc/ The current path,
>   homepage/index/, didn't match any of these.

The urls.py in dms project:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from homepage.views import index # default homepage

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls), 
    url(r'^$', index, name='index'),  # homepage
    url(r'^addexcel/', include('add_excel.urls')), 
    url(r'^addstruc/', include('add_struc.urls')), 
]
```

urls.py in add_excel app:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin
from add_excel.views import IndexView
urlpatterns = [
       url(r'index/', IndexView.as_view(), name ='index'),
       ]
```

urls.py in add_struc app:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin
from add_struc.views import IndexView
urlpatterns = [
       url(r'index/', IndexView.as_view(), name ='index'),
       ]
```

urls.py in homepage app:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin
from homepage.views import index
urlpatterns = [
       url(r'index/', index, name='index'),
       ]
```

views.py in add_excel app:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import os
import os.path
import sys
import datetime
from builtins import int
from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
import pymysql
import xlrd
from xlrd import xldate_as_tuple

# Create your views here.
class IndexView(View):
    template_name = 'add_excel/index.html'
    context={}
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'add_excel/index.html', {})

    def post(self, request):
        # if request.method == 'POST' and 'excel_file' in request.POST:
        if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES["excel_file"]:
            # do something
            return render(request, 'add_excel/index.html', {"excel_data":excel_data})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the name `index` in all of your url patterns which is causing a conflict. These should be properly namespaced (`homepage-index`, `excel-index` etc.) so when you refer to them throughout your application it is obvious to both developers and the program which URL should be chosen.

My theory is that there is some URL generation in your HTML Form that uses the name `index` and your Django site chooses the homepage for the URL so your `IndexView` is not run.

Comment: Thank you! It turns out that the url pattern must be modified like you said and the html file should also be altered, like <form action="{% url "add_excel-index" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> or it may go to wrong page, in this case, the homepage.